# mutation doesn't save ralation id

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I have a problem with `lighthouse graphql` on `laravel`.

Everything works great with queries or simple create/update, but when it comes to relations it becomes hard.

It doesn't save relation.

My example:

**Models**

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'products';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_product';

    public function manufacturer(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Manufacturer::class, 'id_product_manufacturer', 'id_product_manufacturer');
    }

}

class Manufacturer extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'product_manufacturer';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_product_manufacturer';
    protected $fillable = ['name'];


    public function products(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'id_product_manufacturer', 'id_product_manufacturer');
    }
}
```

**sql schema**

```php
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id_product');
            $table->bigInteger('id_product_manufacturer')->unsigned()->index()->nullable();
});

Schema::create('product_manufacturer', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id_product_manufacturer');
            $table->string('name', 64);
});
```

**graphql file**

```
extend type Mutation {
    createProduct(
       input: CreateProduct! @spread
    ): Product @create
}


input CreateProduct {
    manufacturer: CreateProductManufacturerRel
}

input CreateProductManufacturerRel {
    connect: ID
    create: CreateProductManufacturer
}

input CreateProductManufacturer{
    name: String!
}
```

**query sended to server**

```
mutation {
    createProduct(
        input: {
            manufacturer: {
                create: {
                    name: "test"
                }
            }
        }
    ){
        id_product
    }
}
```

This query create new product and manufacturer but it doesn't save `id_product_manufacturer`
into `products` table.

What i have already tried:

https://lighthouse-php.com/master/eloquent/nested-mutations.html#return-types-required

and

https://lighthouse-php.com/master/concepts/arg-resolvers.html#solution

but i don't know where and how create this `resolver function`.
These examples do not explain much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I solved problem.
Problem was in relationship types in laravel models.

This works:

**models**

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'products';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_product';

    public function manufacturer(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Manufacturer::class, 'id_product_manufacturer', 'id_product_manufacturer');
    }

}

class Manufacturer extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'product_manufacturer';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_product_manufacturer';
    protected $fillable = ['name'];


    public function products(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'id_product_manufacturer', 'id_product_manufacturer');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same relation name and also append the relation type in your related input too. For example if a `Product` has one `manufacturer` the input name should be: `CreateManufacturerHasOne`.

So the graphql file should be like this:

```
extend type Mutation {
    createProduct(
       input: CreateProduct! @spread
    ): Product @create
}


input CreateProduct {
    manufacturer: CreateManufacturerHasOne
}

input CreateManufacturerHasOne {
    connect: ID
    create: CreateManufacturerInput
}

input CreateManufacturerInput {
    name: String!
}
```

More information on https://lighthouse-php.com/master/eloquent/nested-mutations.html#hasone.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for response.
Unfortunately, neither answer works.

Still the same, `id_product_manufacturer` is null after send request.

```
mutation {
    createProduct(
        input: {
            manufacturer: {
                create: {
                    name: "test"
                }
            }
        }
    ){
        id_product
    }
}
```

[image]